# Nginx, gunicorn, django, ubuntu - not displaying images

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

fellow humans

I just set up a server on digitalocean and deployed my app. Everything else works fine including my javascript and css. but for some reasons beyond me, uploaded images by a user aren't displaying

I think i got a lead but still dont know where to go.

would really appreciate it if you could point me to the right direction

so here is my image model(upload_to)

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         related_name='images_created')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,
                        blank=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,
                                            db_index=True)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    related_name='images_liked', blank=True)
```

and here is my nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 67.207.87.22;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/kingiyk/stylplus/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
    alias /home/kingiyk/stylplus/media/;
    }




    location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/kingiyk/stylplus/stylplus.sock;
}
}
```

When i upload an image, it gets saved to /home/kingiyk/stylplus/images/2017/07/26

stylplus/images is the image app

I think the '2017/07/26' part is as a result of my *upload_to* being 'images/%Y/%m/%d (year/month/day).

Although the upload is succesful, but the image does not display
i have no problem with my css and javascript.

Now i am guessing there is a conflict between my nginx conf and the path to where the images are stored. please lend a helping hand. cheers

Comment: You are saying that your images are uploaded to `/home/kingiyk/stylplus/images/` however your nginx `/media/` points to `/home/kingiyk/stylplus/media/`.

Comment: You have to serve the image files with nginx. You should change the location of the upload to /home/kingiyk/stylplus/media/ (or static). Or add a new path (images/) to the nginx configuration.

Comment: hey @Tico. i did append my seetings to server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 67.207.87.22;
    
    

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/kingiyk/stylplus/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
 alias /home/kingiyk/stylplus/media/;
    }






    location / {
 include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/kingiyk/stylplus/stylplus.sock;
    }
}
upload_to--'/home/kingiyk/stylplus/media/'
but still cant view uploaded images. any more insights you could share

Comment: Hummmm .  For this solution, you'll need to configure this Path on settings.py also. Basically you have to treat your image files as static files, or media files. Take a look at the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/.

Comment: Just try to save your images on the same folder of your css and ser If ir Works. Then work out a solution to change the path following the static deploy docs

Comment: @Tico when I enter the command python manage.py collectstatic, css, js files and some png files get collected but my uploaded files (mostly .jpg) dont. do you have any idea why that is? I am guessing that could be the root of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works like this: Django Dev server makes things Very easy for us to develop. You Just have to put on settings.py a folder and Django Dev server serves files from that folder, which is 'static' by default. Collect static gets files from inner Django workings and put on this static folder (like admin page css). You dont need that on dev because Django server looks into Django lib folder while nginx dont. So...  not related. For your problem I really recomend that you change the folder where your images are uploaded to the same folder where your css is ('static'). Check If it works. If Works you can Go and configure a New folder on Settings.py and nginx taking the static as example. Look how to configure your 'media' files on Django on this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/.  'media files' is the expression you should look for on Django parlance.

Comment: I think the problem is from my template                                       <a href="{{ image.image.url }}">
            <img src="{{ image.image }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"class="image-detail"></a>when i replace "{{ image.image }}" with {% static "rango.jpg" %}, an image displays but img src="{{ image.image }} doest not display an image. i have a class model named image with an upload_to attribute which uploads my files to /home/kingiyk/stylplus/static/ and in my settings.py, I've got STATIC_ROOT= '/home/kingiyk/stylplus/static/'
STATIC_URL= '/static/'. any idea where i went wrong?